# Conversions to Mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

im having some problems with understanding how to convert instructions to MIPs assembly. the problem is. Write the MIPS assembly for the following instructions. Assume variables a – j are assigned to temporary registers $0 – $8. Assume that the base address of arrays A and D are in $9 and $10. If you need a register to store an intermediate result, you can use any remaining temporary or saved registers or register $at (the assembler temporary register). Convert the assembly codes into machine code

D[i]=A[j]<<6

now , i have it set up like this

1. 0$
2. 1$ a
3. 2$ b
4. 3$ c
5. 4$ d
6. 5$ f
7. 6$ g
8. 7$ i
9. 8$ j

   10. 9$ A
   11. 10$ B

im a confused , because in class , my teacher always started with the SLL (shift logical left) command for the 2 examples we did. my question is do we always do this? im not sure i understand what SLL actualy means/does , so i cant really see if it would benefit this problem. so far i have the firt instruction , this is assuming SLL is the first thing that happens. I thought maybe LW would come first. this is what i got for my answer

1. SLL $11 , $8 , 6
   2.Add $12, $9,$11
2. lw $13,0($12)
3. sll $14,$7,2
4. add $15,$14,$10
5. sw $13,0(15$)

Comment: Are those arrays indexed in words or bytes? There are only 10, not 11 temporary registers, and those are `$8`-`$15`, `$24`-`$25`, not `$0`-`$8`. Please, make your question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it's quite difficult to understand some of the things you mentioned in your post.

Let's say that you want to turn `D[i] = A[j] << 6` into MIPS assembly, knowing that

- `$8` contains the `i` index
- `$9` contains the `j` index
- `$10` contains the `A` array address
- `$11` contains the `D` array address
- `$12` and `$13` can contain anything we want, as temporary registers

We start on the right side, with the operator of the largest priority: `[]`. We know that `A + j` is the address of element `A[j]`, assuming that `j` contains a byte offset from array base. Therefore,

```
add $12, $10, $9  ; $12 = A + j
lw $12, 0($12)    ; $12 = the word at $12 (A[j])
```

Now we do the shift itself, using `sll`

```
sll $12, $12, 6   ; $12 = $12 << 6
```

Having `$12` filled with the calculated right side, we need another register to address `D[i]`

```
add $13, $11, $8  ; $13 = $11 + $8
sw $12, 0($13)    ; stores $12 (right side) to $13 (D[i])
```

Comment: i appologize , but thats exactly how the question is asked lol. why is that  8$ contains i and 9$ contains j?

Comment: i also dont know why my instructions are coming out sideways like that

Comment: i fixed the post AS much as i could

Comment: There are only 10 temporary registers, named from `$t0` to `$t9`. You're code just won't work, as it performs the shift sooner, than retrieves the data to be shifted. Why can't you use this code? Changing registers into other ones is a matter of few seconds.

Comment: Note that you should scale `j` by the element size (which is 4 for words) before using it to load `A[j]`.

Comment: "...assuming that j contains a byte offset from array base". OP doesn't say anything about width of the arrays.